# Election of a new moderator

Tags: discussion, election

I will be stepping down as a moderator soon and have requested the community team to initiate an election for the post. It was really a wonderful experience for me, but I guess I am not able to find enough time these days to perform the mod duties efficiently (new job, change of field and a lot of work). A CM will announce the start of the election soon.

However, I will try my best to spend more time in moderating (as a privileged user) and answering.

If you have any queries regarding the election process, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for all your work. You've also been a big contributing factor for the graduation of this site. Kudos. I hope to see you back often.

Comment: Thanks for your commitment as a moderator, especially to get this site graduated.

Comment: Thanks for the work you've done so far!

Comment: Yes, thanks for you efforts and great work as a mod!

Comment: Ditto. Ditto. Ditto. anddd Ditto. Thanks, @WYSIWYG. Hope you find some time to stay relatively involved! :D

Comment: THANKS @WYSIWYG FOR ALL THE WORK YOU HAVE DONE SO FAR.